how to mask hash users into random values name@domain.com in azure databricks
We have an Excel file in file store that contains more than 10,000 columns of JSON data in each excel file.
for example, a sample like below.
json:
{"SearchName":"","Id":"","RequestType":"","StartDateUtc":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z","EndDateUtc":"2023-04-28T00:00:00Z","RecordType":null,"Workload":"","Operations":[],"Users":["d503246e-285c-41bc-8b0a-bc79824146ea,ingrid.van.driel@vroon.nl,ab6019a4-851c-4af2-8ddc-1e03ee9be97a,bart.van.someren@vroon.nl,85ff7cda-5f2d-4d32-b51c-b88ad4d55b5a,nicky.ongenae@vroon.nl,48168530-659c-44d3-8985-65f9b0af2b85,erwin.weeda@vroon.nl,0937a1e5-8a68-4573-ae9c-e13f9a2f3617,Thessa.vanden.Oetelaar@vroon.nl,c822dd8b-0b79-4c13-af1e-bc080b8108c5,Hester.Blankenstein@vroon.nl,ca0de5ba-6ab2-4d34-b19d-ca702dcbdb8d,Alvin.Baltonado@ph.vroonshipmanagement.com"],"ObjectIds":[],"IPAddresses":[],"SiteIds":null,"AssociatedAdminUnits":[],"FreeText":"multifactor","ResultSize":0,"TimeoutInSeconds":345600,"ScopedAdminWithoutAdminUnits":false}

We just want to change the user hash value to normal mask values.
like this: Alvin.Baltonado@ph.vroonshipmanagement.com  into sam@contoso.com for whole excel file users.
Every time we manually copy users data and masking like below, it takes a lot of time for us. Then, after whatever output we got, we just replaced the hash value with the output.
import random  
  
main=['nzn1@contoso.com', 'oman2@contoso.com', 'oman3@contoso.com', 'oman4@contoso.com', 'oman5@contoso.com', 'oman6@contoso.com', 'oman7@contoso.com', 'oman8@contoso.com', 'oman9@contoso.com', 'omaz1@contoso.com', 'omaz2@contoso.com', 'omaz3@contoso.com', 'omaz4@contoso.com', 'omaz5@contoso.com', 'omaom6@contoso.com', 'omax7@contoso.com', 'omaz8@contoso.com', 'omaz9@contoso.com', 'omay1@contoso.com', 'omay2@contoso.com', 'omaom3@contoso.com', 'omax4@contoso.com', 'omax5@contoso.com', 'omax6@contoso.com', 'omaom7@contoso.com', 'omaw8@contoso.com', 'omaw9@contoso.com', 'omae1@contoso.com', 'omae2@contoso.com', 'omae3@contoso.com', 'omae4@contoso.com', 'omae5@contoso.com', 'omae6@contoso.com', 'omae7@contoso.com', 'omae8@contoso.com', 'omae9@contoso.com', 'omaf1@contoso.com', 'omaf2@contoso.com', 'omaf3@contoso.com', 'omaf4@contoso.com', 'omaf5@contoso.com', 'omaf6@contoso.com', 'omaf7@contoso.com', 'omaf8@contoso.com', 'omaf9@contoso.com', 'omag1@contoso.com', 'omag2@contoso.com', 'omag3@contoso.com', 'omag4@contoso.com', 'omah1@contoso.com', 'omay5@contoso.com', 'omal1@contoso.com', 'omam6@contoso.com', 'omao1@contoso.com', 'omaom2@contoso.com', 'omao4@contoso.com', 'omag5@contoso.com', 'omah2@contoso.com', 'omay6@contoso.com', 'omal2@contoso.com', 'omam7@contoso.com', 'omao2@contoso.com', 'omao5@contoso.com', 'omao6@contoso.com', 'omag6@contoso.com', 'omah3@contoso.com', 'omay7@contoso.com', 'omal3@contoso.com', 'omam8@contoso.com', 'omao3@contoso.com', 'omao7@contoso.com', 'omao9@contoso.com', 'omag7@contoso.com', 'omah4@contoso.com', 'omaq1@contoso.com', 'omaq3@contoso.com', 'omai3@contoso.com', 'omah8@contoso.com', 'omax3@contoso.com', 'omal8@contoso.com', 'oman4@contoso.com', 'omaq2@contoso.com', 'omaq4@contoso.com', 'omaq5@contoso.com', 'omai4@contoso.com', 'omah9@contoso.com', 'omaom4@contoso.com', 'omal9@contoso.com', 'oman5@contoso.com', 'omaom3@contoso.com', 'omaq6@contoso.com', 'omaq8@contoso.com', 'omai5@contoso.com', 'omai1@contoso.com', 'omaom5@contoso.com', 'omam1@contoso.com', 'oman6@contoso.com', 'omaq7@contoso.com', 'omaq9@contoso.com', 'omar2@contoso.com', 'omai6@contoso.com', 'omaw1@contoso.com', 'omaz6@contoso.com', 'omam2@contoso.com', 'oman7@contoso.com', 'omar1@contoso.com', 'omar3@contoso.com', 'omar5@contoso.com', 'omai7@contoso.com', 'omaw2@contoso.com', 'omaz7@contoso.com', 'omam3@contoso.com', 'oman8@contoso.com', 'omar4@contoso.com', 'omar6@contoso.com', 'omar8@contoso.com', 'omai8@contoso.com', 'omay3@contoso.com', 'omaom8@contoso.com', 'omam4@contoso.com', 'oman9@contoso.com', 'omar7@contoso.com', 'omar9@contoso.com', 'omaom1@contoso.com', 'omai9@contoso.com', 'omay4@contoso.com', 'omax9@contoso.com', 'omam5@contoso.com', 'oman7@contoso.com', 'oman8@contoso.com', 'oman9@contoso.com', 'omaz1@contoso.com', 'omaz2@contoso.com', 'omaz3@contoso.com', 'omaz4@contoso.com', 'omaz5@contoso.com', 'omaz6@contoso.com', 'omaz7@contoso.com', 'omaz8@contoso.com', 'omaz9@contoso.com', 'omay1@contoso.com', 'omay2@contoso.com', 'omay3@contoso.com', 'omay4@contoso.com', 'omay5@contoso.com', 'omay6@contoso.com', 'omay7@contoso.com', 'omay8@contoso.com', 'omay9@contoso.com', 'omae1@contoso.com', 'omae2@contoso.com', 'omae3@contoso.com', 'omae4@contoso.com', 'omae5@contoso.com', 'omae6@contoso.com', 'omae7@contoso.com', 'omaan1@contoso.com', 'omaan2@contoso.com', 'omaan3@contoso.com', 'omaan4@contoso.com', 'omaan5@contoso.com', 'omaan6@contoso.com']  
  
l=["0e07209b-807b-4938-8bfd-f87cee98e924,invoices@it.vroonoffshore.com,c747a82c-656e-40eb-9194-88c4a0f8061e"]  
n=len(l)  
print(n)  
print(random.sample(main,n))

My question Is there  any way  in azure databricks replace whole Excel file user json key hash values to random users like this ss@contoso.com at a time and rewrite back to particular location

10,000 coulumns is small dataset - you could use even for-loop to work with every row separatelly, read JSON, convert to dictionary, update data, convert it back to JSON and put in row.

hi furas, Thanks for your response when i try to read excel fill in databricks i am getting error like this [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/Book111.xlsx'. but i have a  excel file  in same directory.

maybe real path is /some/folder/dbfs/FileStore/Book111.xlsx or it has to be relative path without first /. Maybe check "current working directory" os.getcwd() and what you have in this folder os.listdir()

As you mentioned you want to change the user hash value to normal mask values.
I have tried the below approach:
sample_json = """
{"SearchName":"","Id":"","RequestType":"","StartDateUtc":"2022-12-01T00:00:00Z","EndDateUtc":"2023-04-28T00:00:00Z","RecordType":null,"Workload":"","Operations":[],"Users":["d503246e-285c-41bc-8b0a-bc79824146ea,ingrid.van.driel@vroon.nl,ab6019a4-851c-4af2-8ddc-1e03ee9be97a,bart.van.someren@vroon.nl,85ff7cda-5f2d-4d32-b51c-b88ad4d55b5a,nicky.ongenae@vroon.nl,48168530-659c-44d3-8985-65f9b0af2b85,erwin.weeda@vroon.nl,0937a1e5-8a68-4573-ae9c-e13f9a2f3617,Thessa.vanden.Oetelaar@vroon.nl,c822dd8b-0b79-4c13-af1e-bc080b8108c5,Hester.Blankenstein@vroon.nl,ca0de5ba-6ab2-4d34-b19d-ca702dcbdb8d,Alvin.Baltonado@ph.vroonshipmanagement.com"],"ObjectIds":[],"IPAddresses":[],"SiteIds":null,"AssociatedAdminUnits":[],"FreeText":"multifactor","ResultSize":0,"TimeoutInSeconds":345600,"ScopedAdminWithoutAdminUnits":false}
"""
masked_emails = [
    'ss1@contoso.com', 'ss2@contoso.com', 'ss3@contoso.com', 'ss4@contoso.com', 'ss5@contoso.com', 
    'ss6@contoso.com', 'ss7@contoso.com', 'ss8@contoso.com', 'ss9@contoso.com', 'ss10@contoso.com', 
    'ss11@contoso.com', 'ss12@contoso.com', 'ss13@contoso.com', 'ss14@contoso.com', 'ss15@contoso.com', 
    'ss16@contoso.com', 'ss17@contoso.com', 'ss18@contoso.com', 'ss19@contoso.com', 'ss20@contoso.com'
]
def mask_emails(json_str):
    try:
        data = json.loads(json_str)
        users = data.get("Users", [])
        if users:
            original_emails = users[0].split(',')
            masked = random.sample(masked_emails, len(original_emails))
            data["Users"] = [','.join(masked)]
        return json.dumps(data)
    except Exception as e:
        return json_str
mask_emails_udf = udf(mask_emails, StringType())
data = [(sample_json,)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["json_column"])
df = df.withColumn("transformed", mask_emails_udf(col("json_column")))
display(df)

In the above code I am  masking email addresses in JSON data.
Reading the JSON data, replacing the user email addresses with masked values, and then writing the transformed JSON back.
Results:
transformed
{"SearchName": "", "Id": "", "RequestType": "", "StartDateUtc": "2022-12-01T00:00:00Z", "EndDateUtc": "2023-04-28T00:00:00Z", "RecordType": null, "Workload": "", "Operations": [], "Users": ["ss18@contoso.com,ss17@contoso.com,ss9@contoso.com,ss1@contoso.com,ss2@contoso.com,ss20@contoso.com,ss16@contoso.com,ss15@contoso.com,ss6@contoso.com,ss7@contoso.com,ss11@contoso.com,ss4@contoso.com,ss12@contoso.com,ss8@contoso.com"], "ObjectIds": [], "IPAddresses": [], "SiteIds": null, "AssociatedAdminUnits": [], "FreeText": "multifactor", "ResultSize": 0, "TimeoutInSeconds": 345600, "ScopedAdminWithoutAdminUnits": false}



[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dbfs/FileStore/Book111.xlsx'

Error mentions that the Python interpreter is unable to locate the specified Excel file at the given path in your  DBFS.
To resolve the above ERROR and write the results as xlsx format I have tried the below approach:
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
dir_path = "/FileStore/tables/"
dbutils.fs.mkdirs(dir_path)
file_path = dir_path + "transformed_data.xlsx"
local_file_path = "/tmp/transformed_data.xlsx"
pandas_df.to_excel(local_file_path, index=False, engine='openpyxl')
dbutils.fs.cp("file:" + local_file_path, "dbfs:" + file_path)
print(f"File saved to {file_path}")

Results:
dbutils.fs.ls("/FileStore/tables/transformed_data.xlsx")

[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/transformed_data.xlsx', name='transformed_data.xlsx', size=5623, modificationTime=1720070340000)]


hi dileep,thanks for your answers, as mention above i have  Excel file in file store it contains more than 10,000 columns of JSON data .like 10,000 json .
for 1 json already i know how to do normal python code itself.
that json provide for sample structure .wt you stored in sample_json

even i am trying , need to read whole excel and perform users transformation

def mask_emails(user_list):
return ["sam@contoso.com" for _ in user_list]
for col in df.columns:
for idx, json_data in df[col].items():
try:
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)
if 'Users' in json_obj:
json_obj['Users'] = mask_emails(json_obj['Users'])
df.at[idx, col] = json.dumps(json_obj)
except (json.JSONDecodeError, TypeError):
continue

hi dileep , thank's for the comment , firstly is it possible read excel file in spark, if yes could you provide Screen short how you done and also  df . first step is to read excel file .normal when i try to read excel file . i am getting error .

%pip install openpyxl
%pip install xlrd
Install these 2 libararies

import pandas as pd
dbfs_input_path = 'dbfs:/FileStore/tables/sample_excel_file.xlsx'
local_input_path = '/tmp/sample_excel_file.xlsx'
dbutils.fs.cp(dbfs_input_path, 'file:' + local_input_path)
df_readinput = pd.read_excel(local_input_path)
df_readinput.display()

https://i.imgur.com/49rhliX.png

https://i.imgur.com/xz8eDOj.png
